# access private member from a friend class

Tags: c++

Rather than posting for help I wanted to try and figure this out on my own, but after hours of searching Google and watching countless youtube videos I am unsuccessful. What I am trying to do is create a friend class and then from that class access the private members of the "parent" class. I added the `friend class bar` as you'll see below and then tried to use the `.` and `->` notations to access the private members value but no luck. I have a feeling I'm linking correctly, but its just a matter of calling the private member correctly?

**// Headers/classfoo.h**

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
};

class foo {
public:
    friend class bar;
    foo();
private
    node *head;
};
```

**// Headers/classbar.h**

```
class bar {
public:
    int test();
};
```

**// Source/classbar.cpp**

```
int bar::Test() {
    // nothing working
    // head->data;
    // head.data;
}
```

Comment: bar has a pointer to an object of type foo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to perform `head->data` you need a `foo` object in `bar` or passed to `bar::Test()`. Then it might be something like:

```
class bar {
  foo f;
  public:
    int Test();
}
```

and

```
int bar::Test() {
  f.head->data;
}
```

Of course don't forget to initialize the member variable `f`.

Comment: So I did exactly as you had, but I get the error `unknown type name 'foo'`

Comment: Either forward declare `class foo` and make the member variable foo a pointer, or `#include "classfoo.h"`

Comment: @MrPilot basically that new error is unrelated to this specific question about the friend classes.